# If MyOpenID is shut down, why is it showing in login option?

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, login

In an answer for [a *MyOpenID* login-related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265817/myopenid-login-is-not-working), I find that it shut down as of 1st Feb 2014. But then why is the Data Explorer giving me the option to login using *MyOpenID*?

[image: login screen shot]

Please remove it from the login options.

Comment: It's the data explorer, not stackexchange.com (you can see "Data Explorer" written in the logo)

Comment: Data explorer is.. special. It is also [Open Source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer); I'm sure the project would love a pull request to clear this up.

Comment: Yes, only concern is, user like me confuse to use `MyOpenID` for login.

Comment: Produce a pull request for https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/b9e8fcf8746f490ddee46f4165b1e39f046feb4e/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/openid-jquery.js

Comment: @Lafada agreed, no doubt it should be removed, just saying it's a different site than stackechange.com and not under the direct control of SE staff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have some authentication changes for Data Explorer in the pipe that include removing the MyOpenID option, so this is [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned). I'll try to get them out by Monday at the latest, and then give 6-8 weeks for deployment.

Comment: You really should get privilege to add moderator tags here in MSE, maybe limited to questions already tagged [meta-tag:data-explorer]. :-)

Comment: I've adjusted tags accordingly ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Tim Stone for moderator!

Comment: @hichris123 no moderators on MSE :(